Stacked column chart is showing a small zero value sliver at the top of each column
I have a stacked column chart. Each column has three blocks but some of them have zero value.
The columns are displaying the last element as a small, hoverable slice.
I would prefer that this did not show or be hoverable.
How can I disable these from showing?
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function drawStackedChart() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
               ['Columns', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
               ['Column1',  1 ,  0 ,  0],
               ['Column2',  0 ,  1 ,  0]]
          );
          var options = {
               isStacked: true
          };
          new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('stackedChart')).draw(data, options);
     }
     google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStackedChart);
</script>
<div id="stackedChart"></div>



I've tried adding a blank annotation to the end and that didn't help. I am hoping someone can point me the right way to get these little slices to vanish.

I fixed my own problem and am posting for others.
I was forming my JS improperly.
Here is the working version:
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawStackedChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Columns', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
           ['Column1',  1 ,  0 ,  0],
           ['Column2',  0 ,  1 ,  0]]
      );
      var options = {
           isStacked: true
      };
      var chart_div = document.getElementById('stackedChart');
      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(chart_div);
      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    }
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStackedChart);
</script>
<div id="stackedChart"></div>

